# React Material Dropdown size

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Autocomplete from here: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete. It's a fantastic control, but extends pretty far downwards on mobile (which causes it to show behind the keyboard). Is there a way to make such a control display only 3 items, based on if device type is mobile?

Comment: Maybe adding a simple style to its ListboxComponent to set a max height could be enough?

Comment: You can style the listbox via `listbox` rule name in `Authocomplete` components `classes` props. You can find the api here : https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/ . You can set the max height for small screens with css media query.